# Wildcard search of dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

After searching google and SO, I see that there is a way for me to search a dictionary for an existing key:

```
dict.exists("search string")
```

My question is how can I search a dictionary using a wildcard:

```
dict.exists("search*")
```

I want to search the dictionary for a term first because my macro has the user select a group of files (the file name as dictionary key and the full path as the value) and I want to determine if files of a certain naming convention are present in the group BEFORE I iterate the dictionary elements to apply the file processing.

If a certain naming convention is found, X processing is run on each file in the dictionary instead of Y processing.  The trick is that if **ANY** of the elements follow the certain naming convention, then they all need to be processed accordingly.  That is to say, if elements 1-19 fail to meet the convention but 20 passes, then all elements 1-20 need specific processing.  This is the reason I cant just check each name as I go and process selectively one file at a time.

My current solution is to iterate the entire dictionary once searching for the naming convention, then reiterating the dictionary after I know which method to use in processing the files.  I am looping through all the elements twice and that doesn't seem efficient...

Do you guys have a reasonable solution for wildcard searching the dictionary keys?

Comment: Looping through your dictionary keys (even twice) will likely take a fraction of the time it takes to process any files, so I wouldn't worry about it.  Anyway, that's pretty much your only option, since Exists doesn't support wildcard matching.

Comment: OK.  I think that is really the "answer" then, but I want to try these solutions below as work arounds.

Comment: Dick's approach is certainly a good way to wrap up what you want to do in a reusable function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dictionary Items method returns an array of all the items. You can Join those into a big string then use `Instr()` to determine if your search string is in the big string.

From your example, you have the asterisk at the end, so I'm assuming you care how an item starts, not that a sub-string exists anywhere. So I look for delimiter+substring and add the delimiter to the front of the `Join` (for the sake of the first item). If you have different requirements, you'll have to adjust, but the theory is the same.

I used two pipes as a delimiter because it's unlikely to be in the data and return a false positive. That may not be appropriate for your data.

```
Public Function WildExists(ByRef dc As Scripting.Dictionary, ByVal sSearch As String) As Boolean        
    Const sDELIM As String = "||"        
    WildExists = InStr(1, sDELIM & Join(dc.Keys, sDELIM), sDELIM & sSearch) > 0        
End Function
```

*test code*

```
Sub Test()

    Dim dc As Scripting.Dictionary            
    Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary

    dc.Add "Apple", "Apple"
    dc.Add "Banana", "Banana"
    dc.Add "Pear", "Pear"

    Debug.Print WildExists(dc, "App") 'true
    Debug.Print WildExists(dc, "Ora") 'false

End Sub
```

Comment: OP seems to want to search across Keys (file names vs. the full path)  - so should maybe be `Join(dc.Keys, sDELIM)` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Filter combined with the array of dictionary keys to return an array of matching keys.

```
Function getMatchingKeys(DataDictionary As Dictionary, MatchString As String, Optional Include As Boolean = True, Optional Compare As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As String()

    getMatchingKeys = Filter(DataDictionary.Keys, MatchString, Include, Compare)

End Function
```

Here are some examples of what can be done when you apply a filter to the dictionary's keys.

Option Explicit

```
Sub Examples()
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim arrKeys() As String
    Dim key

    Set dict = New Dictionary

    dict.Add "Red Delicious apples", 10
    dict.Add "Golden Delicious Apples", 5
    dict.Add "Granny Smith apples", 66
    dict.Add "Gala Apples", 20
    dict.Add "McIntosh Apples", 30
    dict.Add "Apple Pie", 40
    dict.Add "Apple Sauce", 50

    dict.Add "Anjuo Pears", 60
    dict.Add "Asian Pears", 22
    dict.Add "Bartlett Pears", 33
    dict.Add "Bosc Pears", 44
    dict.Add "Comice Pears", 3

    arrKeys = getMatchingKeys(dict, "Apple")
    Debug.Print "Keys that contain Apple"
    Debug.Print Join(arrKeys, ",")
    Debug.Print

    arrKeys = getMatchingKeys(dict, "Apple", False)
    Debug.Print "Keys that do not contain Apple"
    Debug.Print Join(arrKeys, ",")
    Debug.Print

    arrKeys = getMatchingKeys(DataDictionary:=dict, MatchString:="Apple", Include:=True, Compare:=vbBinaryCompare)
    Debug.Print "Keys that contain matching case Apple"
    Debug.Print Join(arrKeys, ",")
    Debug.Print

    arrKeys = getMatchingKeys(DataDictionary:=dict, MatchString:="Pears", Include:=True, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
    Debug.Print "We can also use the array of keys to find the values in the dictionary"
    Debug.Print "We have " & (UBound(arrKeys) + 1) & " types of Pears"
    For Each key In arrKeys
        Debug.Print "There are " & dict(key) & " " & key
    Next

End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this method can help you with wildcard searching in Dictionary

```
Sub test()
Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim KeY, i&: i = 1
For Each oCell In Range("A1:A10")
    Dic.Add i, Cells(i, 1).Value: i = i + 1
Next
For Each KeY In Dic
    If LCase(Dic(KeY)) Like LCase("Search*") Then
        MsgBox "Wildcard exist!"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The exists function operates on the `dict.keys`. In this answer `LCase(Dic(KeY))` compares a value. However, you can use `LCase(KeY)` instead to compare keys

Comment: @Axel believe me, I know exactly how `exists` works, but please carefully read OP before post your comments, `exists` doesn't support search using a wildcard.

Comment: I wasn't trying to question your knowledge on the exists function. Just trying to help further viewers... I think your answer is the most suitable. However, you check the values for the wildcard, not the keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a wildcard to search in dictionary keys you can use the method *[yourdictionary].Keys* and the function *Application.Match*

For example: 
Dim position As Variant 'It will return the position for the first occurrence

```
position = Application.Match("*Gonzalez", phoneBook.Keys, 0)
```

---

If phoneBook has Keys: (JuanCarlos, LuisGonzalez, PedroGonzalez)

It will return the position for LuisGonzalez