# vlookup splitted through items does not work

Tags: excel, split, vlookup, vba

One time, I asked on SO about a function like vlookup but for a split value. I was using it for a long time. Now, the code no longer seems to work.
What can be reason that code which was working no longer does?

```
Sub test()
Dim Cl As Range, Key As Variant
Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each Cl In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
        If Cl.Value <> "" Then
            Dic.Add Cl.Row & "|" & Replace(LCase(Cl.Value), ";", "||") & "|", Cl.Offset(, 1).Text
        End If
    Next Cl
End With
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each Cl In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
        For Each Key In Dic
            If Key Like "*|" & LCase(Cl.Value) & "|*" And Cl.Value <> "" Then
                Cl.Offset(, 1).Value = Dic(Key)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Key
    Next Cl
End With
End Sub
```

At the moment there is no errors but code is not working. For some people it is working. For me not.
Please see expected result below:

[image]

Comment: Where's your error? Did you change your input data? And more importantly, what is your code supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I felt the need to refactor your code because I just posted an answer on how to do a [Wildcard search of dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246074/wildcard-search-of-dictionary/38608819#38608819).

Could you edit your answer to include sample data from column A of Sheet1 & Sheet2?

```
Sub RefactoredCode()

    Dim Cl As Range
    Dim key, keys, results
    Dim MatchString As String

    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each Cl In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            dic.Add Cl.Row & "|" & Replace(LCase(Cl.Value), ";", "||") & "|", Cl.Offset(, 1).Text

        Next Cl
    End With

    keys = dic.keys

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        For Each Cl In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        MatchString = "|" & LCase(Cl.Value) & "|"
            results = Filter(keys, MatchString, True, vbTextCompare)

            If UBound(results) > -1 Then
                key = results(0)
                Cl.Offset(, 1).Value = dic(key)
            End If

        Next Cl
    End With

End Sub
```

I ran both your `RefactoredCode()` and `Test()`.  Both of them are working properly.

[image]

Comment: I added image with expected result. I hope it can be more clear now.

Comment: @user3114375 I updated my answer.  But both of our codes ran as expected.

Comment: Thank you for response. Unfortunately for me both does not work. For your code in the second sheet in B1 appears 1. That's all.