# Looking for a more efficient script/logic for lookup (loop) OfficeScript

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I managed to make a relatively logical and functional script that takes all empty cells in a column, and then one by one compares a list (separate table) for matching words.
The problem is that is so unbelievably inefficient/slow and memory intesive, in practice it's not useful.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let transactionsTable = workbook.getTable("table_transactions");
  let emptyCatCells = transactionsTable.getColumnByName("category").getRange().getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.blanks)
  let lookupWords = workbook.getTable("table_autoCatReference").getColumnByName("lookupWord").getRange().getValues()

  if (emptyCatCells) {
    // Loop through areas
    for (let i = 0; i < emptyCatCells.getAreas().length; i++) {
      let areaBlankCategory = emptyCatCells.getAreas()[i];
      // Loop through cells
      for (let j = 0; j < areaBlankCategory.getCellCount(); j++) {
        let descEmptyCat = areaBlankCategory.getCell(j, -1)

        for (let lookupWord of lookupWords) {

          if (descEmptyCat.getText().includes(lookupWord)){
 
            areaBlankCategory.getCell(j, 0).setValue("FOUND")
          } else {

          }
        }

        
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log("No blank cells")
  }

}
```

So I have a `table_transactions` with columns `description` and `category`. Also I have a `table_autoCatReference` with `lookupWord` and `matchedCategory`

For every row that has an empty category, I want to lookup `lookupWord`s for a match in the cell for the description of the corresponding empty category. If a match is found, then place the `matchedCategory` (did not get to implement this yet, for now its a static string) for the `lookupWord` in the empty cell of `category` (in the first table)

I sort of got somewhere with my script but in sure it's very questionable.
I would be very interested in learning about superior ways of thinking and implementing this idea.
Thank you.

Comment: One thing that will certainly help is to read the values of each area into an array in the outer loop and then in the inner loop run through the array and fill the gaps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The outer loop returns RangeAreas so as far as I understand (beginner level) I would maybe get an array of arrays  (Range) with the description included, and then in the inner loop use those values, did I get that right?

Comment: Use `Dictionary` object to improve efficiency.

Comment: this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246074/wildcard-search-of-dictionary

Comment: @ceci OP is looking for Office Scripts instead of VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes to improve the efficency

- Load `category` and `description` into array
- Load `lookupWord` into `Dictionary`
- Check description is in dictionary with `desValues[i][0] in dictCate`
- Update `category` col all at once

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let transactionsTable = workbook.getTable("table_transactions");
  let desColumn = transactionsTable.getColumnByName("description").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
  let catColumn = transactionsTable.getColumnByName("category").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
  let emptyCatCells = catColumn.getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.blanks)
  let catValues = catColumn.getValues();
  let desValues = desColumn.getValues();
  let lookupWords = workbook.getTable("table_autoCatReference").getColumnByName("lookupWord").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
  let dictCate: { [key: string]: string } = {}
  // Loop through lookup words and add to dictionary
  for (let i = 0; i < lookupWords.length; i++) {
    dictCate[lookupWords[i][0].toString()] = ""
  }
  if (emptyCatCells) {
    // Loop through all cells in category column
    for (let i = 0; i < catValues.length; i++) {
      // If category is blank
      if (catValues[i][0] === "") {
        // If description is in dictionary
        if (desValues[i][0].toString() in dictCate) {
          // Set category to "FOUND"
          catValues[i][0] = "FOUND"
        }
      }
    }
    // Update category column
    catColumn.setValues(catValues);
  } else {
    console.log("No blank cells")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @taller, this is very advanced! I'm learning so much here! I'll play with this and let you know..

Comment: This is actually it. Have not figured it out completely, but I get the logic and the ballpark of the statements and it is very cool. I'm marking it as the answer, and thank you again, this has been a major struggle for me.